# Problem with output of neural network in a cross-entropy method attempt at solving CartPole-v0

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement the cross-entropy policy-based method to the classic CartPole-v0 environment. I am actually reformatting a working implementation of this algorithm on the MountainCarContinuous-v0, but when I try to get the agent learning, I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 
      5 agent = Agent(env)
----> 6 scores = agent.learn()
      7 
      8 # plot the scores

~/cross_entropy.py in learn(self, n_iterations, max_t, gamma, print_every, pop_size, elite_frac, sigma)
     83         for i_iteration in range(1, n_iterations+1): # loop over all the training iterations
     84             weights_pop = [best_weight + (sigma*np.random.randn(self.get_weights_dim())) for i in range(pop_size)] # population of the weights/policies
---> 85             rewards = np.array([self.evaluate(weights, gamma, max_t) for weights in weights_pop]) # rewards from the policies resulting from all individual weights
     86 
     87             # get the best policies

~/cross_entropy.py in (.0)
     83         for i_iteration in range(1, n_iterations+1): # loop over all the training iterations
     84             weights_pop = [best_weight + (sigma*np.random.randn(self.get_weights_dim())) for i in range(pop_size)] # population of the weights/policies
---> 85             rewards = np.array([self.evaluate(weights, gamma, max_t) for weights in weights_pop]) # rewards from the policies resulting from all individual weights
     86 
     87             # get the best policies

~/cross_entropy.py in evaluate(self, weights, gamma, max_t)
     56             action = self.forward(state)
     57             #action = torch.argmax(action_vals).item()
---> 58             state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
     59             episode_return += reward * math.pow(gamma, t)
     60             if done:

/gym/wrappers/time_limit.py in step(self, action)
     14     def step(self, action):
     15         assert self._elapsed_steps is not None, "Cannot call env.step() before calling reset()"
---> 16         observation, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
     17         self._elapsed_steps += 1
     18         if self._elapsed_steps >= self._max_episode_steps:

/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py in step(self, action)
    102     def step(self, action):
    103         err_msg = "%r (%s) invalid" % (action, type(action))
--> 104         assert self.action_space.contains(action), err_msg
    105 
    106         x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot = self.state

AssertionError: tensor([ 0.3987,  0.6013]) () invalid
```

I found this is because the MountainCarContinuous-v0 environment has an action_space of type Box(2) whereas CartPole-v0 is Discrete(2), meaning that I only want an integer as action selection.

I have tried working around this notion by applying a softmax activation function and then took the index of the higher value as the action.

```
action_vals = self.forward(state)
action = torch.argmax(action_vals).item()
```

This gets rid of the error but when I train the agent, it seems to learn incredibly fast which is kind of an indicator that something is wrong. This is my full agent class:

```
class Agent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, env, h_size=16):
        super().__init__()
        self.env = env
        # state, hidden layer, action sizes
        self.s_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.h_size = h_size
        self.a_size = env.action_space.n
        # define layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.s_size, self.h_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.h_size, self.a_size)

        self.device = torch.device('cpu')
        
    def set_weights(self, weights):
        s_size = self.s_size
        h_size = self.h_size
        a_size = self.a_size
        # separate the weights for each layer
        fc1_end = (s_size*h_size)+h_size
        fc1_W = torch.from_numpy(weights[:s_size*h_size].reshape(s_size, h_size))
        fc1_b = torch.from_numpy(weights[s_size*h_size:fc1_end])
        fc2_W = torch.from_numpy(weights[fc1_end:fc1_end+(h_size*a_size)].reshape(h_size, a_size))
        fc2_b = torch.from_numpy(weights[fc1_end+(h_size*a_size):])
        # set the weights for each layer
        self.fc1.weight.data.copy_(fc1_W.view_as(self.fc1.weight.data))
        self.fc1.bias.data.copy_(fc1_b.view_as(self.fc1.bias.data))
        self.fc2.weight.data.copy_(fc2_W.view_as(self.fc2.weight.data))
        self.fc2.bias.data.copy_(fc2_b.view_as(self.fc2.bias.data))
    
    def get_weights_dim(self):
        return (self.s_size+1)*self.h_size + (self.h_size+1)*self.a_size
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.fc2(x))
        return x
        
    def evaluate(self, weights, gamma=1.0, max_t=5000):
        self.set_weights(weights)
        episode_return = 0.0
        state = self.env.reset()
        for t in range(max_t):
            state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().to(self.device)
            action_vals = self.forward(state)
            action = torch.argmax(action_vals).item()
            state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
            episode_return += reward * math.pow(gamma, t)
            if done:
                break
        return episode_return

    def learn(self, n_iterations=500, max_t=1000, gamma=1.0, print_every=10, pop_size=50, elite_frac=0.2, sigma=0.5):
        """PyTorch implementation of the cross-entropy method.
        
        Params
        ======
            n_iterations (int): maximum number of training iterations
            max_t (int): maximum number of timesteps per episode
            gamma (float): discount rate
            print_every (int): how often to print average score (over last 100 episodes)
            pop_size (int): size of population at each iteration
            elite_frac (float): percentage of top performers to use in update
            sigma (float): standard deviation of additive noise
        """
        n_elite=int(pop_size*elite_frac) # number of elite policies from the population

        scores_deque = deque(maxlen=100) # list of the past 100 scores
        scores = [] # list of all the scores
        best_weight = sigma*np.random.randn(self.get_weights_dim()) # initialize the first best weight randomly

        for i_iteration in range(1, n_iterations+1): # loop over all the training iterations
            weights_pop = [best_weight + (sigma*np.random.randn(self.get_weights_dim())) for i in range(pop_size)] # population of the weights/policies
            rewards = np.array([self.evaluate(weights, gamma, max_t) for weights in weights_pop]) # rewards from the policies resulting from all individual weights

            # get the best policies
            ##
            elite_idxs = rewards.argsort()[-n_elite:] 
            elite_weights = [weights_pop[i] for i in elite_idxs]
            ##

            best_weight = np.array(elite_weights).mean(axis=0) # take the average of the best weights

            reward = self.evaluate(best_weight, gamma=1.0) # evaluate this new policy
            scores_deque.append(reward) # append the reward
            scores.append(reward) # also append the reward
            
            torch.save(self.state_dict(), 'checkpoint.pth') # save the agent
            
            if i_iteration % print_every == 0: # print every 100 steps
                print('Episode {}\tAverage Score: {:.2f}'.format(i_iteration, np.mean(scores_deque)))

            if np.mean(scores_deque)>=195.0: # print if environment is solved
                print('\nEnvironment solved in {:d} iterations!\tAverage Score: {:.2f}'.format(i_iteration-100, np.mean(scores_deque)))
                break
        return scores
```

If anyone has an idea on how to get the agent training properly, please give me any suggestions.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was to add an act() method to the Agent class.

```
def act(self, state):
        state = state.unsqueeze(0)
        probs = self.forward(state).cpu()
        m = Categorical(probs)
        action = m.sample()
        return action.item()
```